# Free Charts in Monodroid

Tags: graph, charts, mono, xamarin.android

first of all, I'm sorry but my Engilsh isn't good.

I was looking for how can I draw a Chart in Monodroid during 5 or 6 hours, and I didn't find anything. I only found TeeChart(steema) but I don't want to pay.

**Does anybody know a free way?**

Thanks. It's my first post.

Comment: So you spent 6 hours looking for a free alternative, instead of working on the business problem at hand?  Not sure the cost of TeeChart, but if your time is worth anything, it seems like you probably already would have paid for some or all of a commercial product.

Comment: I'm internship in a Company, and they told me to look for an altenative. It cost 300$ more or less. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a Java component, e.g.:

[GraphView](https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView)

[AChartEngine](http://www.achartengine.org/index.html)

And bind it to use in Mono for Android using their Java integration:

[Binding a Java Library](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/binding_a_java_library_%28.jar%29)

Comment: Tomorrow i'll try this. It seems difficult. Thanks.